# How can I differentiate between third-party and custom modules in the list of modules?

Tags: 7

If I have administrative access to a Drupal site, I can see the list of the modules enabled for the site.

How can I differentiate between third-party and custom modules?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this by looking at sites/all/modules folder - if the sitebuilder was a good one you will see two folders "custom" and "contrib". In modules administration page there is no simple way to differentiate between them.

Comment: I can't look on those folder, because i have the admin access of the site only, not the server access.

Comment: @JasodeepChatterjee, FYKI, you should provide this information in main question, as this is VITAL information, so if there is not a information, answerer will provided the most primary and usual way to solve your issue, As he do not know what restrictions you have..:)

Answer (score 2):

Since custom modules are not hosted on Drupal.org, their .info files will not containing their version info. A module hosted on drupal.org (for example, the *Entity API* module) will contain the following information that a custom module will not have.

```
; Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2016-03-17
version = "7.x-1.7"
core = "7.x"
project = "entity"
datestamp = "1458222244"
```

So, in the *Version* column shown in admin/modules, you will not see any version number.

[image: screenshot]

The *User flag* module you see in the screenshot is a custom module I created.

Comment: Even this is not for sure as we do versioning our custom modules as well. In this case even the custom modules not hosted on Drupal.org have a version number

Comment: Do you add a line like `version = "7.x-1.7"` in the .info file?

Comment: Usually - if we do any versioning - yes... do you think it is not such a good idea in general?

Comment: It's is not causing any security issue, but I would avoid it. If you are using Git or any other VCS, you already get versioning. Eventually, you could add a comment at the beginning of the module, if you need a version number that is more _human readable_.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Hacked](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module to differentiate.

> This module scans the currently installed Drupal, contributed modules
>   and themes, re-downloads them and determines if they have been
>   changed. Changes are marked clearly and if the diff module is
>   installed then Hacked! will allow you to see the exact lines that have
>   changed.

If it is a custom module you can see that module in different color from "/admin/reports/hacked"

Comment: The is a live site , where i have to differentiate modules. It might be a good solution. But i guess this one is not for me ! !

Answer (score 1):

Or Use Module filter and have all of your custom modules in Custom package. Then you will be able to see all of the custom modules in Custom tab on admin/modules page.

Comment: Someone should open a feature request in Module Filter. Filter by directory "custom", "contrib" etc.

Comment: There is no need of use a specific package value for custom modules. You can easily see which modules are custom modules without installing additional modules.

Answer (score 1):

If the Update manager module is enabled, you can simply go to the Available updates page (/admin/reports/updates).

Custom modules, not hosted by drupal.org, will not have information available and will be shown in grey.